# Ionic 2 custom font not carrying over to android device

Tags: cordova, angular, ionic2

## I'm using a custom font-family on my Ionic 2 project.

On ionic serve --labThe font-family appears just fine (*see first image*).

[Image of the font-family used in the menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AjfY.jpg)

And if I run the app on the android (ionic view and sdk) the font-family used on the device is never the one I've seen on the browser(see second image) . why?

[Font-family that appears on android device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGqn2.jpg)

Comment: Just to get the obvious out of the way first, but can you try adding one explicitly for each platform? `<ion-icon name="home" ios="ios-home" md="md-home"></ion-icon>`  "md" is for material design

Comment: Updated question, the problem is only on the font-family, thank you.

Comment: Well this seems to be an issue with the files copied to your android platform, check if you can see your fonts inside of the android folder. If not, copy your fonts inside of the folders that should be (inside of your android folder) just to validate if that is the issue.

Comment: All the font files that exist on ionic main assets folder also exist on the platforms/android/assets/www/assets/fonts  folder.

Comment: how did u include the fonts files?